# How do I Develop IOS application without having Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I only have a Windows 7 PC, Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin, and an Android phone. I want to develop android and ios application using xamarin, but I have no idea how to do that without mac. Please help me to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Requirement Except what you have now

- A credit card or a Paypal account.

Go To - https://www.macincloud.com/

Connect with the Website, choose the appropriate solution and remember to check the Remote Build Port - SSH AddOn to allow you to use Xamarin Mac Agent.

[image]
[image]

When you have completed the registration, you’ll receive an email with the login credentials and the Mac IP. Follow the instructions listed in it to get the first access to your virtual Mac machine.

Now you have configured you Mac

Now you can goto Xamarin Mac agent and connect to cloud mac to your VS

[image]

enter username and password

YES, now you ready for the IOS development in Visual studio on Windows